# Why linux kernel lights up the screen again before the machine's actually put to hibernation

Tags: kernel

When putting the machine to hibernation, the screen's like black -> light up -> black, after that the machine actually put to hibernation. I'm wondering why the kernel lights up the screen again during the process?

Comment: this isn't systematic across all hardware or distro versions. I don't have this for example

Comment: Yeah, it only affects Intel integrated cards I think.